# Full Outer Join two selects into one data set for analysis

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have large datasets where I would like to compare the data. For instance a compare between budget and actuals. Depending on which (management)level this is discussed I need similar queries.

Datasets:

```
Year                float
Period              float
Weeknumber          float
Account             nvarchar(255)
Customer            nvarchar(255)
Account manager     nvarchar(255)
Market              nvarchar(255)
Country             nvarchar(255)
Customercode        float
Customername        nvarchar(255)
Article             float
Description         nvarchar(255)
Productgroup        nvarchar(255)
Line                nvarchar(255)
Fresh               nvarchar(255)
OwnProduction       nvarchar(255)
NNNRevenue          decimal(10, 2)
CM                  decimal(10, 2)
Pieces              decimal(10, 2)
KG                  decimal(10, 2)
TriggerId           nvarchar(255)
YearWeek            nvarchar(255)
```

Most basic query:

```
SELECT [Article]
      ,sum([NNNRevenue]) as Revenue
      ,sum([Pieces]) as Pieces
      ,sum([KG]) as KG

  FROM [PP_Test].[dbo].[history]

  where year = '2018'
  and period = '2' 

  group by Article
  order by Article
```

Result will look like:

```
Article  Revenue    Pieces   KG
6852     123548,12  654813   13248,61
10031    489642,15  4687896  56478,54
4477     4698,78    54846    46,15
```

I have the exact same query for [PP_Test].[dbo].[budget]. What I need is a (full?) join where my new result will be any Article in either the budget or history file.

Example result wanted:

```
Article  H.Revenue  H.Pieces H.KG      B.Revenue  B.Pieces  B.KG
6852     123548,12  654813   13248,61  51346,12   321558    87156,12
10031    489642,15  4687896  56478,54  541326     21314     13215,15
4477     4698,78    54846    46,15     321564,74  14548     132147,87
16531    0          0        0         1278,15    1348      1348,15
55555    123151,15  13234    154884    0          0         0
```

My code

```
SELECT h.[Article]
      ,sum([NNNRevenue]) as RevenueHis
      ,sum([Pieces]) as PiecesHis
      ,sum([KG]) as KGHis
     ,RevenueBud
     ,PiecesBud
     ,KgBud

  FROM 
  (
SELECT [Article]
      ,sum([NNNrevenue]) as RevenueBud
      ,sum([Pieces]) as PiecesBud
      ,sum([KG]) as KGBud

  FROM [PP_Test].[dbo].[budget]

  Where year = '2018'
  and Period = '2'
  group by Article
  ) as B

  Full outer join [PP_Test].[dbo].[history] as H
  on B.Article = H.Article

  where year = '2018'
  and period = '2' 

  group by h.Article, RevenueBud, PiecesBud, KGBud
  order by h.Article
```

This results in the table I want but I miss items which exist in the budget but not in the history (actuals). This seems to be because of the select on h.article, but I need that to not get the ambiguous name error.

When I get this to work I want to duplicate it to different levels like analysis on customer/article/line etc. and as next step make reports in srss where variables are declared and used by users to make selections on period, year etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filtering on a `full outer join` is tricky.  One way is to use a subquery:

```
SELECT COALESCE(B.Article, h.Article) as Article,
       RevenueHis, PiecesHis, KGHis,
       RevenueBud, PiecesBud, KgBud
FROM (SELECT [Article], sum([NNNrevenue]) as RevenueBud,
             sum([Pieces]) as PiecesBud, sum([KG]) as KGBud
      FROM [PP_Test].[dbo].[budget]
      WHERE year = 2018 AND Period = 2
      GROUP BY Article
     ) B FULL JOIN
     (SELECT Article, sum([NNNRevenue]) as RevenueHis,
             sum([Pieces]) as PiecesHis, sum([KG]) as KGHis
      FROM [PP_Test].[dbo].[history] as H
      WHERE year = 2018 AND period = 2
      GROUP BY Article
     ) H
     ON B.Article = H.Article
ORDER BY h.Article;
```

Note:  Storing `year` and `period` as `float` is silly.  `INT` makes sense.  `DECIMAL(4)` makes sense.  Even a string.  But don't use floating point representations unless that is what you really intend.

Similarly, don't put single quotes around numeric constants.  Single quotes should only be used for date and string constants.

Comment: Agreed on the datatypes, it's just the way I 'inherited' it. Will probably do it differently if I recreate the data.

Comment: When I try your code on microsoft sql server I get an error: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'.

Comment: Thanks this is really close to what I need, now I have a couple of rows with null as values, this I don't mind, but also some rows with null as article number, which is somewhat of a problem for further analysis.

Comment: @A.vanEsveld . . . You just need to `COALESCE()` the two articles together.  For the other `NULL`s, you can use `COALESCE()` if you prefer `0`.